# MondoDB - Why should you embed a document inside a document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Im looking to use MongoDB for my database implementation. Why would you want to embded a document insode a document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one way to do what in a relational database you would do with a JOIN (something that you cannot do in MongoDB).

For example, you could have a MongoDB document as a blog post, and embed the list of comments right in there.

Then you can (for example):

- load post and comments in a single query
- search for posts which have replies
- search for posts by user A which have replies by user B
- atomically update both post and comments in a single transaction

All that would be impossible (or at least difficult) if the comments were stored in their own collection as separate documents.

Comment: ok, i see. So using your blog post example, say i wanted to store tags for a post. I can embed a list of tags in the blog post which would save me searching a whole collection for tags for a specific blog post. What if i also created a collection for tags so that i can count the number of times a tag was used? So embed tags in a post and have a seperate collection for tags with a count. Would mongoDB be able to handle a query across all posts to count the number of times a specific tag was used? or is a seperate tag collection suitable?

Comment: "Would mongoDB be able to handle a query across all posts to count the number of times a specific tag was used?". Yes, you can count all documents that use that tag. If the tag is indexed, that should be quite fast, too.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, embed if its NOT a top level object, if it does NOT have complex relationships, if there will be a lot of duplicate data if you do NOT embed, and if your documents become bigger then a few megabytes.

Taken from the MongoDB site: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Summary of Best Practices

- Embed "First class" objects, that are at top level, typically have their own collection.
- Line item detail objects typically are embedded.
- Objects which follow an object modelling "contains" relationship should generally be embedded.
- Many to many relationships are generally done by linking.
- Collections with only a few objects may safely exist as separate collections, as the whole collection is quickly cached in application server memory.
- Embedded objects are a bit harder to link to than "top level" objects in collections.
- It is more difficult to get a system-level view for embedded objects. When needed an operation of this sort is performed by using MongoDB's map/reduce facility.
- If the amount of data to embed is huge (many megabytes), you may reach the limit on size of a single object. See also GridFS.
- If performance is an issue, embed.